# GO inconsistent declaration

Tags: go, constants, declaration

I'm a noob at GO, Just starting to learn the language.
why is this fine:

`const name, age = "Kim", 22`

but this is not

`const name, age := "Kim", 22`

Answer (score 5):

From [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/basics/15):

> Constants cannot be declared using the `:=` syntax.

`:=` is used to declare a variable inferring its type from the value. Though, declaring and initializing a variable is not the same as declaring a constant. See also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/go/go_variables.php) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-t-constants-be-declared-using-the-syntax-in-Golang).

Comment: Okay, It seems there a bit of nuances in GO I need to get familiar with. Thanks